# Distribution and Mail-enabled Security groups are not visible on Admin portal and can't be queried via graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I was able to create a Distribution/Mail-Enabled Security group via the Microsoft Admin portal. But after creation I am unable to see it in the group list and can't fetch it via Graph API but the are visible on the exchange admin center. Also the older groups are still visible and can be fetched via API too.
We can see the Microsoft 365 or Security group after creation as usual.

Comment: If you create a group in Active Directry, it takes time to sync to Azure AD. It will not be immediate. The default synchronization cycle happens every 30 min. Please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-scheduler#overview). Once its synced to azure ad, you can get the group using MS GRaph.

Comment: Even if its AAD/AD, when you created distribution group/mail enabled security groups, it may take some more time to showup, depending on your infrastructure/setup/settings. When i gave try in my AAD account, it took 1-2 minutes and it was up and running. Also i can able to make the Graph API to make the call for these groups - it worked. If you see lot of time to sync or it's not happening then it's not issue with Graph API, rather i suspect it might be issue with your AAD settings. Please consider filing a support ticket with Microsoft through your portal.azure.com, they can help you.